# Night Light in Ubuntu Turns on, then Immedietly turns off. What's going on?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This has been an issue as long as I have been using Linux. I have searched for weeks on how to fix this but no results. I've tried using RedShift but no use.

My suspicion might be because it's not working because I'm using a "Display Port" on my first monitor and it's confusing the heck out of the OS.

I am on Ubuntu 21.04.

My main question is if there are any alternatives to bypass this bug? f.lux and Redshift is a no go. I really don't want to strain my eyes at night while programming.

Comment: Are you able to get **Redshift** to see your location correctly? What happens when you run Redshift from the terminal?

Comment: Welcome, you say _"This has been an issue as long as I have been using Linux."_, that means it happened with other distros/versions of linux?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue, but I doubt it has anything to do with the fact that you're using Display Port. It's only started happening for me after I changed my time settings to use local instead of whatever not local was because it was messing up the time for whenever I would boot into Windows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).